# Download manger not able to download large files in android

Tags: android, server, backend, android-download-manager, kotlin-android

By large file i mean 8.5 MB and by small files I mean 80KB to 1MB.

> while download manager can download files up to 2GB

The below code is able to download small files but not large one. For the large files it shows the downloading notification but then after some time shows 0kb/unknown (waiting for retry) in the notification. And in the logcat there is no error or any kind of message which can point to this problem. I'm calling this code from a normal service() class.

```kotlin
    if (PermissionsUtil.hasExternalStoragePermission(context)) {
                if (fileName.isNotBlank() && mimeType.isNotBlank()) {
                    // get download service and enqueue file
                    Toaster.showMessageShort(R.string.download_started)
                    manager?.let {
                        enq = it.enqueue(getDownloadManagerRequest(link, mimeType, fileName, withHeader))
                        context.registerReceiver(downloadCompletionReceiver, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
                    }
                }
            }
```

PS:

Im able to download large file in the postman using the same URL which is being provided to the download manger.

My network is working fine, I have tried with 6 different phone on different networks, all the showing the same behaviors.

On trying to listen to all the events while the (large) file is getting downloaded I get the below event

> PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY

**Update**

So I tried [these](https://testfiledownload.com/) test pdf files of various different sizes (100MB to 1GB), they are getting downloaded without any issue. But the 8.5MB whose URL im getting in an API response is showing the PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY message.

And I also noticed one thing, when I tested the 1GB file in postman it just took almost half a second to send request after that it started downloading the file, but when I tried the 8.5MB one it almost takes more then a mintune in sending the request.

So is there anything like "Time Out" which can be set on a download manager because I think that might be the case, that the url is taking lot of time in sending the request and in the main time download manger runs out of time. (Just an assumption)

Comment: Can you yourself create or put such big files on your Android device?

Comment: yes its able to create such file

Comment: Can you download the file with a browser on your device?

Comment: yes, the problem is not with the device I have tried on 6 different phones as well. same is happing with them

Answer (score 1):

Download manager has limitation only with available disk space. To check downloading status you need to use download id returned by `enqueue(...)` method. Check this example

```
private val statusHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
private val statusRunnable = Runnable {
     downloadStatusQuery(downloadId)
}

private fun downloadStatusQuery(id: Long) {

    val downloadQuery = DownloadManager.Query()
    downloadQuery.setFilterById(id)

    val cursor = mDownloadManager.query(downloadQuery)
    Thread {
        cursor.use { cursor ->
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                downloadStatus(cursor, id)
            }
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun downloadStatus(cursor: Cursor, id: Long) {

    //column for download  status
    val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
    val status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex)
    //column for reason code if the download failed or paused
    val columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON)
    val reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason)
    var statusText = ""
    var reasonText = ""
    val bytesTotal = cursor.getLong(
        cursor.getColumnIndex(
            DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES
        )
    )

    when (status) {
        DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED -> {
            statusText = "STATUS_FAILED"
            when (reason) {
                DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME -> reasonText = "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND -> reasonText = "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS -> reasonText =
                    "ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR -> reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ERROR"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR -> reasonText = "ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE -> reasonText =
                    "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS -> reasonText =
                    "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE -> reasonText =
                    "ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE"
                DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN -> reasonText = "ERROR_UNKNOWN"
            }
          statusHandler.removeCallbacks(statusRunnable)
        }
        DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED -> {
            statusText = "STATUS_PAUSED"
            when (reason) {
                DownloadManager.PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI -> reasonText = "PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI"
                DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN -> reasonText = "PAUSED_UNKNOWN"
                DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK -> reasonText =
                    "PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK"
                DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY -> reasonText =
                    "PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY"
            }
            statusHandler.postDelayed(statusRunnable, 2000)
        }
        DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING -> {
            statusHandler.postDelayed(statusRunnable, 2000)
            statusText = "STATUS_PENDING"
        }
        DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING -> {
            statusHandler.postDelayed(statusRunnable, 2000)
            statusText = "STATUS_RUNNING"
        }
        DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL -> {
            statusText = "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL"
            statusHandler.removeCallbacks(statusRunnable)
        }
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Status $statusText : $reasonText : ID: $id")
}
```

Comment: STATUS_PENDING    ->   STATUS_RUNNING (multiple times)   -> 
  STATUS_PAUSED : PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY. and then from STATUS_RUNNING is started looping.

Comment: @TehleelMir  You need to research deeper. Check your link at browser app and if download works verify params for `DownloadManager` otherwise this is not `DownloadManager` issue and should be fixed at server side. And if possible check the same with different internet providers

Comment: I'm able to download the same file using the URL in the postman, and the app is already working fine for the small files. But for files which have size between 8MB to 20MB are show the above behavior. This clarifies the two things 1. The network is fine and also the backend server.

Comment: @TehleelMir Postman is good but you need android environment. Check with any REST Api Client app. I'm sure you're close to find the reason

Comment: i have updated my answer please read that, and is there anything like timeout on the download manger which can be set I think that might be the cause, I tried to look on web but seems nothing there on this topic

Comment: @TehleelMir Do you have valid url? Is it contain spaces, special characters, file extension ?

Comment: Man that url is working fine in the postman already, please read the update which I added to my question..

Comment: @TehleelMir Your question is about `DownloadManager`. It's not the same as Postman.

Comment: No i mean the url is ok, its just taking a more time then usually for requesting, so is there any way by which I can increment the timeout limit of download manager